# Pass spreadsheet data in addRows() as an array

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization, spreadsheet

I'm using [this Calendar Chart guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#data-format) and instead of adding static data within `dataTable.addRows` component of the script within HTML, I'm trying to pass data from [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WPsErMO7ypNoJAfecupcJEDjf5YvGH5PrdSxoT6Cky8/edit#gid=0]) that contains only 2 columns ('Date' & 'Number' type columns).

When I print the result of my function, copy-paste that within the `dataTable.addRows` component as static value, it works!

I've tried passing data in both "array" and "string" format but constantly keep getting the following error in Chrome browser's console -
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.`

and
`Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table).`

I've also tried creating a `for` loop and using *addRow* instead of addRow**s** but that did not work either.

[The script](https://script.google.com/d/1okt_lZFtpmvDpooJzXN1-XJXD6Lo5h5Zk34X_je6mANS0gGReeItds9-/edit?usp=sharing) has been deployed as a web app and can be accessed [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyzAZQeOmxH7ttGBVC_RUg741x0KuqwB1i9d-R7moV_ON6KtHc/exec).

**Array format: getEventsArrayFormat**

```
function getEventsArrayFormat() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = activeSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var rowDisplay = range.getLastRow();
  var columnDisplay = range.getLastColumn()
  var data1 = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < rowDisplay; i++ ) {
    var rowData = [];
    data1 = data1 + "[ new Date('"
    for (var j = 0; j < columnDisplay; j++ ) {
      if (j == 0) {
        data1 = data1 + values[i][j] + "'), "
      } else if (j == 1 && i < rowDisplay - 1) {
        data1 = data1 + values[i][j] + " ],"
      } else if (j == 1 && i < rowDisplay) {
        data1 = data1 + values[i][j] + " ]"
      }
    }
    rowData.push(data1)
    data1 = data1 + "\n";
  }
  return rowData;
}
```

**String format: getEventsStringFormat**

```
function getEventsStringFormat() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = activeSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var rowDisplay = range.getLastRow();
  var columnDisplay = range.getLastColumn()
  var data1 = '';
  for (var i = 1; i < rowDisplay; i++ ) {
    data1 = data1 + "[ new Date('"
    for (var j = 0; j < columnDisplay; j++ ) {
      if (j == 0) {
        data1 = data1 + values[i][j] + "'), "
      } else if (j == 1 && i < rowDisplay - 1) {
        data1 = data1 + values[i][j] + " ],"
      } else if (j == 1 && i < rowDisplay) {
        data1 = data1 + values[i][j] + " ]"
      }
    }
    data1 = data1 + "\n";
  }
  Logger.log(data1)
  return data1;
}
```

Hoping to be able to see the exact same view, as per what's shared in Google's gallery, by using the data from the spreadsheet.

Comment: Also, I don't intend to make my sheet public either - or so is recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#creating-a-chart-from-a-separate-spreadsheet)

Comment: You could directly return `values` without any modifications or just JSON.stringify the array and parse it

Comment: @TheMaster - tried both of those options as well but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can't pass dates using google.script.run checkout these [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values). So just convert them to strings.  If you want them to be dates on the clients side then convert them back with JavaScript.

```
function getEventsArrayFormat() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    vA[i][0]=Utilities.formatString('%s/%s/%s',new Date(vA[i][0]).getMonth()+1,new Date(vA[i][0]).getDate(),new Date(vA[i][0]).getFullYear());
  }
  return vA;
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the restrictions and I've added your piece of code as part of `getEventsArrayFormat2` but its providing with an output in a rather unusual format than what I'm used to dealing with -

Comment: this is the format -
5/30/2017,0,5/31/2017,0,6/1/2017,1,6/2/2017,2,6/3/2017,2,6/4/2017,0

but as per [this Calendar Chart guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#data-format) would you mind sharing as to how can I pass it as an object?
I suppose that should be in -
[5/30/2017,0],[5/31/2017,0],[6/1/2017,1] & so on...

Comment: Here's what my data looks like for the same spreadsheet data `[["5/30/2017", 0], ["5/31/2017", 0], ["6/1/2017", 1], ["6/2/2017", 2], ["6/3/2017", 2], ["6/4/2017", 0], ["6/5/2017", 2], ["6/6/2017", 1], ["6/7/2017", 1], ["6/8/2017", 1], ["6/9/2017", 1],`

Comment: I've never used the Calendar Chart before but in looking at the example I get the impression that you will need to convert those date strings back into dates.  So you can split them on `/` and then it will be `new Date(Array[2],Array[1],Array[0])` and passing them as an array should be okay

Comment: Ah! My bad :) This resolved the issue 100% Thanks a ton for the tip - I figured out how to process it from the html side of things.

Comment: Just saw your new comment - I did it the other way though :)